# WFS request using layer extent or spatial query QGIS3

Tags: qgis, layers, wfs, spatial-query, request

I'm trying to request features from wfs-service by using a virtual layer. Is it possible to load features by using a layer extent from a virtual layer?

I know how to add dimension for a request with ogr2ogr but how can I do same thing in QGIS?

Comment: why use a virtual layer, why not interact directly with the WFS

Comment: what do you mean? The database only contains point data. I know how to use operators like 'like' '=' ect. But how to use some sort of extent/bounding box. I know there is an option where I can only request features by map extent but I need to be more specific.

Comment: I mean that QGIS can read a WFS service directly, without you having to set up some virtual layer.   when you say `The database only contains point data.` which database do you mean here?